# C program is not adding correctly when looping over an array

Tags: c

I was trying to find the sum of 5 numbers (in C Language) using tutorials from "thenewboston" on Youtube. My code is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    int array[5]={a, b, c, d, e};
    int sum=0;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Enter your 5 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum+=array[i];
    }

    printf("The sum of 5 numbers is:%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

But the weird thing was, no matter what 5 numbers I entered, I always got the sum as 48.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? What is the value of `a`, `b`, `array[0]`  etc...?

Comment: Please don't bite learners. Learning pointers is hard.

Comment: How can I store them in that array using the same format? I saw Bucky did the same way in his tutorials, but he put in numbers instead of variables

Comment: Try moving your original (inline) array initialization code to just before your for loop. See what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Either discard variables `a, b, c, d, e` and the `array` remains or vice versa

Remove variables on your first printf:

```
print("Enter 5 numbers: ");
```

Don't put variables when you did't use them.

When you put scanf as `scanf("%d, %d", &var1, &var2);`, you must also input the same format as

```
Enter 5 numbers: 10, 20
```

Working example(more efficient with array):

```
int main() {
    int input[5];
    int sum;

    printf("Enter 5 numbers: ");
    scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &input[0], &input[1], &input[2], &input[3], &input[4]);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sum += input[i];
    }

    printf("The sum is %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't storing `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, or `e` into the array `array`. You need to store them in the array after you read them in.

Your declaration of `array` doesn't create an array of pointers to your variables - it creates a single pointer to a contiguous block of five integer fields. You can't update those array fields by just using the addresses of `a`, etc., since your array doesn't point to them.

The most obvious, clear, and simple way to store them in the array (which I recommend) is:

```
array[0]=a;
array[1]=b;
array[2]=c;
array[3]=d;
array[4]=e;
```

Do this just before the beginning of your `for` loop.

Comment: How can I store them in that array using the same format?

Comment: I did, but it still returned the same value